# how to break two lines automatically in html text tag pre

Tags: javascript, html, layout

I have this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <title>any</title>
  </head>
  <body>
          <pre style="width: 150px; white-space:pre-wrap; word-wrap:break-word;">
            word1 word2
            mean1 mean2
          </pre>

  </body>
</html>
```

when I have a small device HTML break lines showing something like this

word1
word2
mean1
mean2

And I expect something like this

word1
mean1
word2
mean2

But I can't change de order of words inside the tag pre because when a I have a bigger device the behavior is ok.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you are describing.

Comment: Yes, i simplified the situation. Let me update with a real code.

Comment: Why are you using `<pre>`?  
How about changing to `<pre>
word1 mean1
word2 mean2
</pre>`.
You CAN change the order = it will still be ok in a "bigger device"...

Comment: I refreshed the code.
so man I am using pre because my backend send me text formatted, só i can't change the text.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior, if you want to re-order you need to readapt your css using media-query, or even make a second html for this case.

See for my alternative solution.

```css
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
pre{
  width:50px;
}

div{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.mobile{
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<pre>
word1 word2
mean1 mean2
</pre>

<div>
<pre>
word1
mean1 
</pre>
<pre>
word2
mean2
</pre>
</div>

<div class="mobile">
<pre>
word1
mean1 
</pre>
<pre>
word2
mean2
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that is the problem.. I use media to keep my page responsive, but when I use a mobile device.. The line breaks one by one as we normally expect. and I need to break lines two by two.. but i can't change the text because my back end send by my the whole text.

Comment: So you need to parse the text from your back to generate in JS the tag (see my updated answer, with the behavior you expext)